# CoreMotion Gyroscope apple watch

Tags: core-motion, watchos

I'm trying to get access to the gyroscope of the apple watch. From what I read it is available in watchos 3. Unfortunately I cannot get it to work. It keeps coming back with "Gyro not available" so motionManager.isGyroAvailable is always false. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreMotion



class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1

    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    if (motionManager.isGyroAvailable == true) {
        motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let rotationX = data.rotationRate.x
            let rotationY = data.rotationRate.y
            let rotationZ = data.rotationRate.z
            // do you want to want to do with the data
            print(rotationX)
            print(rotationY)
            print(rotationZ)
        })
    } else {
        print("Gyro not available")
    }
```

Comment: How are you testing?  I've not seen print used that way...  are you perhaps testing on the simulator?  I believe gyro is only available on device.

Comment: Im testing it on the device itself, not in the simulator. All coremotion is available only on the device.

Comment: just a guess: did you request user permission to use Motion and Fitness in ios app?

Comment: @user1602074 hello, did you solve this issue? please reply, thanks.

Comment: same issue here. Interesting tho: `isDeviceMotionAvailable` on the same place is always true, and `startDeviceMotionUpdates(_:_:)` returns gyro data correctly.

Comment: @abjurato hi did you end up with a working version of the gyroscope CM on watchOS? I am currently having 0 problems with the accelerometer but the gyroscope doesn't return any data i.e. `motionManager.isGyroAvailable` always returns false whereas `motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable` returns true

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use CMDeviceMotion's rotationRate?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience (although I can't find it documented anywhere) raw gyroscope data isn't available on the watch, only the processed data. You can access the processed data using the [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager) method:

`startDeviceMotionUpdates(to queue: OperationQueue, withHandler handler: @escaping CMDeviceMotionHandler)`

The `CMDeviceMotion` object in the handler has detailed rotation data, for instance the [rotation rate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotion/1615967-rotationrate), the documentation for this states that it's processed data from the gyroscope. There is also [attitude data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotion/1616050-attitude).

Comment: As of Feb 18 2018, all my attempts to startGyroUpdates(to:) on WatchOS 4.2.2 have  failed.