# Logging Gyro data on watchOS4

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to log gyro data on `watchOS4`, but the following codes do not return the gyro data.

**The same code works on iOS.**

```
manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
manager.gyroUpdateInterval = FPS;
[manager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
[manager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                     withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
                         if( error ) {
                             NSLog(@"Gyro is not available");
                         }else{
                             NSLog(@"Gyro is available");
                             gyro[0] = gyroData.rotationRate.x;
                             gyro[1] = gyroData.rotationRate.y;
                             gyro[2] = gyroData.rotationRate.z;}
                     }];
```

Comment: Related: [CoreMotion Gyroscope Apple Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650961/coremotion-gyroscope-apple-watch)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sample code [Swing Watch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SwingWatch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017286)

from Apple to see if you can get it works.